# How to make focused row highlighted by border on XtraGrid

Tags: winforms, focus, devexpress, highlighting, xtragrid

Currently, I can highlight focused row by changing background appearance color in RowStyle event. But it does not provide to change border of that row.

I tried override **DrawFocusRectangle** of XPaint but it will not be shown in case the grid is not focused.

Anybody gives me another way, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [CustomDrawCell](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) event and paint the row border.

[How to draw thick cell borders by handling the Paint event](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2732.aspx)

If you want to achieve excel like selection functionality, the paint event will give you a better result - http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q202033.aspx